# PWA - is the offline mode an obligation?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I'm really new to the concept of `PWA` and after some researches I have found that the website should be responsive, having the right icons for multiple platforms... I know that the `PWA` now are more supported in many browsers even if for `iOS/Safari` many evolutions (without the support of the push notifications) are on `iOS 14` (correct me please if I'm wrong). But I'm confused about the offline mode, specially while checking the [LightHouse](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lighthouse-pwa-analysis-tool) .

If my app will not support the offline mode, is this a criteria to not be considered as a `PWA`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically a PWA needs to have an installer (a webworker that defines which files are downloaded and made available when installing). However, this may simply be an offline page stating that an internet connection is required.

What I understand from the LightHouse documentation you linked: It checks for several features one usually expects of a progressive web app. So I guess it will require that there are at least a webmanifest including icons and a name. And it will probably check if there is at least one page available when opening the app. In addition it might warn you that not all features of your app work offline if this is the case.